# Fight detection with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, detection, opencv3.0

I found few interesting articles about detection of violent behavior in the crowd:
http://web.eee.sztaki.hu/home4/node/21
http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/2012papers/gnhy/nh15.pdf

So what is the best way to implement such thing with OpenCV? Should i use look into optical flow or anything else? 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: i use deep learning-based approach using CNN to find the best spatial feature and LSTM to handle the relation over time, my work in this URL, and its considre the state-of-the-art in both speed and accuracy
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8852616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure optical flow or feature detection between frames would not help much because although they would track body movements, the computer cannot associate that with fighting. I would suggest looking into programs like Caffe, implemented by Berkeley, which uses neural networks to identify things based off learning from models.

Answer (score 2):

This is still an open topic in computer vision. Most of these approaches are based on motion estimated with optical flow methods. The final classification is mostly done by the bag-of-words approach, support vector machine and a good feature/descriptor the [MoSIFT](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/2009/CMU-CS-09-161.pdf) has been show not achieve good performances on such data. I can recommend the following papers:

[Hassner et al. 2012](http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/data/violentflows/violent_flows.pdf) and proposed [dataset](http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/data/violentflows/)

[Bermejo et al. 2011](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rahuls/pub/caip2011-rahuls.pdf) and an own [dataset](http://visilab.etsii.uclm.es/personas/oscar/FightDetection/index.html)

we also published on violence detection [Senst et al. 2015](http://elvera.nue.tu-berlin.de/files/1479Senst2015.pdf). This work has been implemented using opencv as it contains various tools for video processing. But most of the work have to be done by you.